# Parsing meta data in RSS feed PHP

Tags: php, rss

I am trying to extact the IMG SRC value out of the below RSS feed (only partial feed below).

I am currently using XML parser to get the rest of the items - which works fine (e.g.):

```
foreach($xml['RSS']['CHANNEL']['ITEM'] as $item) 
{
...

            $title = $item['TITLE'];
            $description = $item['DESCRIPTION'];
            $link = $item['LINK'];
        $desc_imgsrc = <how do i get this for below RSS feed??>;
...
}
```

However - how do i get the IMG SRC value from below RSS feed into a PHP variable? Specifically i am trying to extact "**http://thumbnails.---.com/VCPS/sm.jpg**" string into $desc_imgsrc variable above? How can i adapt above code to do that? Thanks.

```
<item>
<title>Electric Cars - all about them</title>
<metadata:title xmlns:metadata="http://search.--.com/rss/2.0/Metadata">This is the title metadata</metadata:title>
<description>This is the description</description>
<metadata:description xmlns:metadata="http://search.---.com/rss/2.0/>
<![CDATA[<div class="rss_image" style="float:left;padding-right:10px;"><img border="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" width="10" src="http://thumbnails.---.com/VCPS/sm.jpg"></div><div class="rss_abstract" style="font:Arial 12px;width:100%;float:left;clear:both">This is the description</div>]]></metadata:description>
<pubDate>Fri, 25 Nov 2011 07:00 GMT</pubDate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is HTML (XML) inside an XML CDATA element. [CDATA (character data)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) is not parsed by the XML parser. You need to extract the value the same way you did with the other elements. Then you can parse the element value, either by using a regular expression or even better use an XML parser again (if the HTML data is valid XML).

Comment: Thanks. that will work  $desc_imgsrc = $item['METADATA:DESCRIPTION'];

Answer (score 0):

```
$doc = new DomDocument;
@$doc->loadHTML(...); // html string
// use @ to supress the warning due to mixture of xml and html

$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($items as $item)
{
  $src = $item->getAttribute('src');
}
```